# What's the regex pattern for finding code comments starting with an apostrophe or a double slash?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a language definition for prismjs that will highlight Xojo code.

Comments in Xojo can be any of the following:

```
' A comment
// Another comment
rem A third comment
```

Comments can be inline, that is the following is valid:

`dim a As Integer // still a comment`

There are no multiline comments.

So far I have figured out how to highlight comments starting with the apostrophe using this regex pattern:

`/'.*/`

but I can't figure out the other two. Could anybody help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a look behind:

```
/(?<=\/\/|'|\brem ).*/
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/jU1VeGk53A).

This matches the *comment* (not the delimiter).

Comment: Thanks. I love this site.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
/('|\/\/|\brem\b).*/
```